# Flash AS2 - Duplicated MovieClips disappearing from stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am facing a problem with my flash project. I am making my own version of a spaceship fighting game. At one point I want to randomly spawn enemies. Here is what I am doing.

I have a movieclip in the library called enemyShip, AS-Linkage is normalEnemy. Object not placed on the scene.
On the actionScipt on that frame, I have the code bellow, which does that for me. What is happening is this: The first two enemies spwan properly, starting from the third each new spawn hides, but does not delete, the one before it. the second enemy is the first to disappear. The first enemy stays visible. Ideas please? I have tried duplicateMovieClip and attachMovieClip and they both have the same result. Sorry for the long question!

```
var origEnemy:MovieClip = _root.attachMovie("normalEnemy", "origEnemy",  this.getNextHighestDepth();
var numberOfEnemies:Number = 1;
var enemyIndex:Number = 0;

_root.onLoad();
 {
     spawnEnemy();
     interval = setInterval(spawnEnemy,1000 + Math.random() * 2000);
 };
// Spawns new enemies
function spawnEnemy()
{
    if (numberOfEnemies > 10)
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    // Randomly calculate the starting coordinates of newly spawned enemy   
    var x_position = Math.random() * 50;
    var y_position = Math.random() * 700;

    // spawn a new enemy and assign random location   
    enemiesArray.push(origEnemy.duplicateMovieClip("enemy" + enemyIndex, this.getNextHighestDepth()));

    //_root.attachMovie("normalEnemy","enemy" + enemyIndex,this.getNextHighestDepth());

    // assign random location
    enemiesArray[enemyIndex]._x = x_position;
    enemiesArray[enemyIndex]._y = y_position;

    // incerement number of enemies
    numberOfEnemies++;
    // Increment enemy Index
    enemyIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation on `duplicateMovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001290.html):

> If the parent movie clip is deleted, the duplicate movie clip is also deleted.

Use [`attachMovie`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001278.html) instead. This will prevent the parent movieclip from being deleted, which will stop the issue you're having.

Additionally, you need to use `_root.getNextHighestDepth()`. Otherwise you risk attaching every object at the same depth... killing off your duplicates again.